# Is it possible to have a Conditional Compilation for ASP.NET comment?

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to do something like this

```
<# if ANYPREPROCESSORCONSTANT #>
<%--
<# endif #>
```

Is it  possible (I want to put an asp.net COMMENT conditionally, I don't want to call a method conditionaly) ?

Update: seems impossible finally nobody could give any right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<% #if DEBUG %>
<div id="debug"></div>
<% #else %>
<div id="release"></div>
<% #endif %>
```

Though it's not very readable in my opinion...use it only if needed!

Comment: Hi thanks but I don't really want to debug, I want to include the ASP.NET comment CONDITIONALY (it could be any other constant as debug)

Comment: I want to exclude some ASP.NET code at DESIGN TIME depending on the value of a preprocessor constant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you define compilier constants for a Web Site project in the web.config, as shown below. Note the comment must be fully enclosed within the #if...#end if construct. Otherwise, you are commenting out the #end if.

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
        <compiler compilerOptions="/d:DEBUG,TRACE,DEBUG_SURVEYCODE,GPT,TRACE_ARGS,TRACE_ARGS_OUTPUT,TRACE_FILES,DEBUG_USER" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

---

```
 <% #if TRACE_ARGS_OUTPUT %>
 <!-- this traces output comment -->
 <% #end if %>
 <% #if TRACE_ARGS_OUTPUT = FALSE %>
 <!-- this does not output comment -->
 <% #end if %>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that, will be helpfull (though that's not a direct answer to my question about asp.net comment).

Answer (score 0):

Since  you said design time, I'm assuming you're referring to [Server Control Design Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh45wzs.aspx)?

You will have to handle the conditional in your design-time code behind...

```
#if SOMEDEFINE
DoSomething();
```

#endif

Comment: I don't want to call function, I just want to put asp comment conditionnaly :)